# Why is IllegalStateException not thrown after calling two terminal operations on the same stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, illegalstateexception

I was given to understand that `collect()` and `forEach()` were both stream terminal operations and that calling them both on the same stream would throw an `IllegalStateException`. However, the following code compiles successfully and prints the length of each String in ascending order. No exceptions are thrown. How can this be so?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ant", "bird", "chimpanzee", "dolphin");
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
        .forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a));
```

Comment: Why do you believe that you call `foreach` on the original Stream and not the object returned by `collect`? How else should `collect` work when it wouldn't return something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` method that you are calling is not the `Stream::forEach` method, but the [`Map::forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method, as you are calling it on the return value of `collect(...)`, which is a `Map`. A feature of the `Map::forEach` method is that it takes a `BiConsumer`, instead of a `Consumer`. A stream's `forEach` never takes a lambda with two arguments!

So you are only calling one terminal operation, namely `collect` on the stream. After that point, you never did anything with the stream again (you started working with the returned `Map`), which is why no `IllegalStateExcepton` is thrown.

To actually call two terminal operations on the same stream, you need to put the stream into a variable first:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ant", "bird", "chimpanzee", "dolphin");
Stream<String> stream = list.stream(); // you need this extra variable.
stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
stream.forEach((a) -> System.out.println(a)); // this will throw an exception, as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

The stream generated for `list.stream()` is consumed by the `collect` operation. But the operation, as a result of grouping, produces `Map<Integer, List<String>>` based on the size of strings.

The `forEach` then is called upon the entries of this `Map` produced by `collect`, hence there is no `IllegalStateException` thrown for the latter.